# Inspección de variables visual en R

Tags: r, machine-learning

Estoy intentado realizar este ejercicio para aprender R pero estoy bloqueado con este apartado.

Tomaremos el dataset de aprobación de crédito bancario en https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Credit+Approval .
La información del dataset está en https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/crx.names

1.Carga los datos. Realiza una inspección por variables de la distribución de aprobación de crédito en función de cada atributo visualmente. Realiza las observaciones pertinentes. ¿ Qué variables son mejores para separar los datos?

Como se podría hacer?

Comment: Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so], lee [ask] y también [por qué es importante demostrar que intentaste algo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/).

Comment: Bienvenido Daniel, por favor lee los enlaces que te pasaron, es importante para entender como funciona la comunidad.  Tu pregunta parte de un lugar que desconocemos, el ejercicio que te has planteado, ¿que significa separar datos?.  ¿Podrías explicar de que se trata el ejercicio y puntualmente que se busca en el punto 1 que mencionas? Por otro lado, siempre pedimos, en el caso de los ejercicios, que el autor de la pregunta demuestre algún esfuerzo por resolverlo , por lo que te sugiero que agregues el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora.